# To display the image from the S3 bucket to the Freemarker PDF but I got an error

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-s3, freemarker

To display the image from the S3 bucket to the Freemarker PDF but I got an error.

I created an API for generated PDFs using Freemarker and I need to display the images inside the PDF file and it should be get from the S3 bucket.

I converted the file from the S3 bucket into byteArray and displayed it in the template.FTL

<img src="data:image/png;base64,${imageBase64}"/>

Anyone could help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Here's the error:

[image]

```
Code to generate PDF data.

fun generatePdfData(templateName: String, data: Any?): ByteArray {
    val html = StringWriter().use { stringWriter ->
        cfg.outputFormat = HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE
        cfg.getTemplate(templateName).process(data, stringWriter)
        stringWriter.toString()
    }
    return ByteArrayOutputStream().use { os ->
        rendererBuilder
            .withProducer(CREATORS.random())
            .withHtmlContent(html, "")
            .toStream(os)
            .run()

        os.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

```
Configuration of template loader.

private val cfg: Configuration = Configuration(
        Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29
    ).apply {
        setClassForTemplateLoading(this.javaClass, RESOURCE_BASE_TEMPLATE_DIR)
        isAPIBuiltinEnabled = true
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(MANILA_TIME_ZONE_ID)
        sqlDateAndTimeTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault() // Freemarker docs told me to do this.
        defaultEncoding = "UTF-8"
        templateExceptionHandler = TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER
        logTemplateExceptions = false
        wrapUncheckedExceptions = true
        fallbackOnNullLoopVariable = false
        setSharedVariable("moneyToWords", TradukistoDirective())
    }
```

```
Fonts list.

private val fonts = listOf(
    "NotoSans-Regular.ttf" to "BodyText",
    "NotoSans-Bold.ttf" to "BodyText",
    "NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf" to "BodyText",
    "NotoSans-Italic.ttf" to "BodyText",
    "NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf" to "BodyTextBaybayin",
    "NotoSerif-Regular.ttf" to "HeaderText",
    "NotoSerif-Bold.ttf" to "HeaderText",
    "NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf" to "HeaderText",
    "NotoSerif-Italic.ttf" to "HeaderText",
    "MPLUS1p-Regular.ttf" to "BodyTextJP",
    "MPLUS1p-Bold.ttf" to "BodyTextJP"
)
```

```
rendering builder.

private val rendererBuilder: PdfRendererBuilder = PdfRendererBuilder()
    .useFastMode()
    .usePdfUaAccessbility(true)
    .usePdfVersion(1.7f)
    .usePdfAConformance(PdfRendererBuilder.PdfAConformance.PDFA_3_A)
    .useUriResolver { _, uri ->
        // We have a custom URI resolver because the built-in one doesn't work with resources or something.
        val loader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
        val path = loader.getResource(Paths.get(RESOURCE_BASE_TEMPLATE_DIR, uri).toString())?.toString()
        path
    }
    .also { builder ->
        // We load in all of the fonts, loading bold and italic ones by-convention.
        fonts.forEach { (resource, name) ->
            val fontPath = Paths.get(RESOURCE_BASE_FONT_DIR, resource).toString()
            val style = when {
                resource.lowercase().contains("italic") -> BaseRendererBuilder.FontStyle.ITALIC
                else -> BaseRendererBuilder.FontStyle.NORMAL
            }
            val weight = when {
                resource.lowercase().contains("bold") -> 700
                else -> 400
            }
            builder.useFont(
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(fontPath)
                        ?: throw FileNotFoundException(CM0080 + resource)
                },
                name,
                weight,
                style,
                true
            )
        }
    }
```

```
class TradukistoDirective : TemplateDirectiveModel {
    override fun execute(
        env: Environment?,
        params: MutableMap<Any?, Any?>?,
        loopVars: Array<out TemplateModel>?,
        body: TemplateDirectiveBody?
    ) {
        if (loopVars?.isNotEmpty() != false) {
            throw TemplateModelException(CM0090)
        }
        if (body != null) {
            throw TemplateModelException(CM0100)
        }

        val value = params?.get("value")?.let { (it as SimpleNumber).asNumber as BigDecimal }
            ?: throw TemplateModelException(CM0110)

        val output = if (value > Integer.MAX_VALUE.toBigDecimal()) {
            "NUMBER TOO LARGE"
        } else {
            val converter: MoneyConverters = MoneyConverters.ENGLISH_BANKING_MONEY_VALUE
            converter.asWords(value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
                .replace("£", "and")
                .plus(" only")
                .split(" ")
                .joinToString(" ") { it ->
                    if (it !in setOf("and", "only")) {
                        it.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() }
                    } else {
                        it
                    }
                }
        }

        env!!.out.append(output)
    }
}
```

```
directories.

companion object {
    const val RESOURCE_BASE_TEMPLATE_DIR = "pdfTemplates"
    const val RESOURCE_BASE_FONT_DIR = "pdfFonts"
    val CREATORS = listOf(
        "Nep", "Yui", "Mio", "Mugi",
        "Asuza", "Ritsu", "Lalatina", "Darkness",
        "Aqua", "Megumin", "Kazuma", "Renge",
        "Hotarun", "Senjyougahara", "Hanekawa", "Nadeko",
        "Hachikuji", "Kizuna", "Araragi", "Arararagi",
        "Ararararagi", "Kagyua Luna", "KAGUYA LUNA!", "Miku",
        "Luka", "Madoka", "Homura", "Sayaka",
        "Kyoko", "Llenn", "002", "Sinon",
        "Jibril", "Sora", "Shiro", "Shuvi",
        "Riku", "Regu", "Nanachi", "Mitty",
        "Yuri", "Yuuri", "Viktor", "Honoka",
        "Kurisu", "Kuristiiiina", "Okabe", "Okarin",
        "Hououin Kyoma", "Leskinen", "Mayuri", "Mayushii",
        "Illya", "Shining Finger", "Daru", "Mr Braun",
        "Suzuha", "Rukako", "Ruka", "Faris",
        "Moeka", "Noire", "Pururut", "Plutia",
        "Doggo", "Subaru", "Rem", "Ram",
        "Emilia", "Puck", "Pack", "Dogoo",
        "Shinobu", "Kiss-Shot Acerola-Orion Heart-Under-Blade", "Burg", "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "Albedo", "Shalltear", "Momonga", "Momon Saaa-aaan",
        "2B", "9S", "A2", "Saber",
        "Rin Tohsaka", "Mai Sakurajima", "Sakuta", "Tomoe",
        "Rio", "Nodoka", "Kaede", "Snorlax",
        "Peroronccino", "Alice-senpai", "Blue Tundra", "Holo",
        "Captain Falcon"
    ) // If nobody knows what we used to generate the pdf it's more secure, right?
}
```

to determine why colon : is illegal and did not display the image from image.ftlh file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)